# SQL Server Standard edition, does it limit the number of Work Threads?

Tags: sql-server

I have a server with 128 logical processors, 64 bits server, and with a Standard edition of SQL Server 2014, and my question is this:

Considering that SQL Server connects an ERP with a high number of simultaneous connections (approximately 1,000), and the characteristic "Maximum calculation capacity" for each of the editions of SQL Server, the standard edition indicates 16 logical processors as the maximum supported, I understand that this has an impact on the "Workers Threads", that is, instead of supporting "4480", it is using only "704". Is what I'm saying about Workers Threads correct?

I leave the links with the features of SQL Server, and the configuration on the "Work Threads":

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This would be a better question for Server Fault.

Comment: @Strom Sounds more like a DBA issue.

Comment: @TT This has more to do with Windows Licensing. Accessible processor sockets and cores are based on the Windows License, and **then** the database edition may further limit CPU cores.(Installing an 16 core Standard Edition of SQL Server on an OS limited to 8 cores still runs on only 8 cores even if the system has 128 cores) I agree with you that this is applicable to both audiences.

Comment: If you do end up stuck with this configuration, Disable Hyper-Threading or Simultaneous Multi-Threading(smt).  This way each logical processor has "full speed" on each core. SMT speeds up tasked switched processes per core, but will degrade performance, if most of the threads are expected to run near 100% utilization.

Comment: @Strom Yes it fits more than one SE site :-). What I read in [Configure the max worker threads Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option) documentation, is that 704 is the standard setting for 64 bit processor, 16 processors. AFAICT, this number can be raised. One should have a clear case to change the default setting though. Note: never changed it myself.